# AngularJS / javascript - flatten unique values object into SIMPLE list

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, flatten

I have a dynamically generated, multi level nested object of UNIQUE values. I want to flatten it (using either AngularJS or vanilla JS) and create a simple array or object of each key / value. So if the object looks like this :

```
[ 

{name : "parent",
 age: 21,
 children: [
     { name : "child",
     dob: [{
         day: "01",
         month: "01",
         year : "82"
     }],
     children: [
     { 
        name : "grandchild",
        dob: [{
            day: "01",
            month: "01",
            year : "02"
            }]
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
}

];
```

The flattened object should look like this :

```
"name":"parent",
"age":21,
"children.name":"child",
"children.dob.day":"01",
"children.dob.month":"01",
"children.dob.year":"82",
"children.children.name":"grandchild",
"children.children.dob.day":"01",
"children.children.dob.month":"01",
"children.children.dob.year":"02"
```

I have found 2 functions to flatten an object, but both insert indexes next to every node. (0.children.0.children.0.dob.0.year) This is no use to me, and not necessary as my values are unique. I need the format above. You can see the functions i'm currently using in this codepen : 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMXEmB

Can anyone help me remove those pesky "zeros" from my final object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brutal, but instead of

```
toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
```

You can remove the 0s like so:

```
let index = i === "0" ? '' : i + '.';
toReturn[index + x] = flatObject[x];
```